# UPDATE and return some rows twice

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, union, common-table-expression

I try to update and return rows. The problem is I use a nested select with `UNION` to get some rows twice and I want to get them returned twice. Example:

Table:

```
First_name | last_name | ready
-----------+-----------+------
john       | doe       | false
           | smith     | false
jane       |           | false
```

Query:

```
With list(name) as (
    Select First_name 
    from table1 
    where First_name Not null and ready=false
    union
    Select last_name 
    from table1 
    where last_name Not null and ready=false
)
Select * from list
```

This returns:

```
John
jane
doe
smith
```

Now I want to update the rows found by the `select` and use `update ... returning` instead. But the `update` only returns the three affected rows, while I want it to return the rows as the `select` in the example does. Is there any way?

Comment: Do you mean RETURNING ? UPDATE table SET name = 'new' RETURING *; http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html

Comment: I want to replace "Select * from list" with something like "Update list Set ready = true Returning *;" but update can not update "list", it can just update and return the original table. I need the table list to be returned.

Comment: It would help if the table1 had a primary key, or *at least* a way to uniquely identify records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with list(name) as (
    select first_name 
    from table1 
    where first_name is not null and ready=false
    union all
    select last_name 
    from table1 
    where last_name is not null and ready=false
), u as (
    update table1
    set ready = true
    where
        (first_name is not null or last_name is not null)
        and
        not ready
)
select * from list
```

You need `union all` to have the four rows. It is `is [not] null`

Comment: Thanks! That's it. I didn't get to set the update into the WITH-list. The union all I just missed writing the example.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite to:

```
WITH cte AS (
   UPDATE table1
   SET    ready = true
   WHERE (first_name IS NOT NULL OR last_name IS NOT NULL)
   AND    NOT ready
   RETURNING first_name, last_name
   )
SELECT first_name FROM cte WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT last_name  FROM cte WHERE last_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Same result, just shorter and faster: This query accesses `table1` a single time instead of three times like in your original.
(Verify the superior performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on a test table.)

[`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html) like [@Clodoaldo already mentioned](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html). `UNION` would eliminate duplicates, which is substantially slower (and probably wrong here).

Comment: Thanks. Smart solution!